# how to free a linked-list that has structures cells inside?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I would like to know what's wrong with my supression function that should free the memory allocated for a linked list.

Here are my codes:

```
typedef struct cell {
int number;
struct cell *next;}cell;

typedef struct {
int sign; //1 or 0
int nbrCell ;
cell *numbers;} num ;
```

The Initialization funtion :

```
num *initialisation(){

num *num = malloc(sizeof(*num));
cell *cell =malloc(sizeof(*cell));

num->numbers = cell;
cell->next=NULL;
num->sign= 0 ;
num->nbrCell =0;
return num ;}
```

the delete procedure

```
void suppression(num* num){

  cell* Delete;
  cell* newC = num->numbers;

   while (newC)
   {
   Delete = newC;
   newC = newC->next;
   free(Delete);
       }
           }
```

Now in my Main I have

```
int main(){
num* number;
number=initialisation();
suppression(number);
 return 0;
  }
```

And when I try the valgrind it says:

```
==21281== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21281==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==21281==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==21281== 
==21281== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==21281==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind  /vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21281==    by 0x4005CE: initialisation (test.c:26)
 ==21281==    by 0x4006D5: main (test.c:85)
 ==21281== 
 ==21281== LEAK SUMMARY:
 ==21281==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
 ==21281==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==21281==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==21281==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==21281==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==21281== 
 ==21281== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
 ==21281== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

even when I try to insert some numbers , I always get that there is 1 allocs extra , like 5 allocs , 4 frees..

In my project I used the number structure to save numbers

like  1->2->3->4->5->6->NULL
      2 is the num->numbers->next etc..

and every time I add a number , it gets put into a cell and then I add the cell to the number structure.
Now I want to know how to free the num and of course free all the cells that it has..

the insertion function

```
  void insertion(num *number, int element ){

  cell *cellule = malloc(sizeof(*cellule));
  if (number == NULL || cellule == NULL)
  {
   exit(-1);
   }
   cellule->number = element;


       cellule->next = number->numbers;
       number->numbers = cellule;
       number->nbrCell++ ;

         }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you add elements to your list?

Comment: Okay but In this example I haven't added any elements , it's just the initialization of the list and trying to remove it , I will add the code I use to add elements

Comment: The code you have in your question works for me without segmentation fault.

Comment: Yeah I tried it again now it works , but still when I use assert(number==NULL); it gives me an error , which means that the number is still allocated..

Comment: So in your `supression()` you need to add `free(num); num = NULL;` but otherwise your code should work

Comment: Okay I added what you said on the code above , still the assert gives an error and the valgrind says I have allocated 32 bytes , and did 1 free , so that the exit there are 16 bytes allocated still..

Comment: So one free wasn't executed, you should check for it using gcc or a few printf().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this doesn't work, there is a problem with your list, other way the problem comes from `num->nbrCell`

```
void suppression(num* num){

   cell* Delete;
   cell* newC = num->numbers;

   while (newC) // != NULL is implicit
   {
       Delete = newC;
       newC = newC->next;
       free(Delete);
   }
}
```

Comment: Now the segmentation fault is gone but when I make an assert(number==NULL) in the main function after I call the suppression procedure, it gives me an error..

Comment: I never used assert(), what does valgrind tells you? By the way, I suspect `free(newC)` to be the cause of the segfault. Anyway, checking for `NULL` seems safer than using a counter to me.

Comment: valgrind gives me 2 errors  
2 allocs , 1 frees , 32 bytes allocated

Comment: I just checked your initialisation function, you forgot `cell->next = NULL`. I'm surprised valgrind isn't complaining about this...

Comment: Okay look , I have removed the cell malloc line from the initialization function 

and now the valgrind says that there is no error .. 180 bytes allocated , 180 bytes free'd , so the problems comes from the cell I think.

Plus I added what you said , it still gives me an error , I think in the suppression function there is 1 cell that hasn't got free'd..

Comment: Using my while or your for?

Comment: @Zok Ho! `num->numbers = NULL;` should be `num->numbers = cell;` !

Comment: Where that ?

And now I tried doing some insertion and did the valgrind , it seems that there is always 1 block that hasn't got free'd .. the problems comes from the malloc in the initialization function

Comment: @Zok In your initialisation , you set `num->numbers` to NULL, in suppression, you get newC like this `newC = num->numbers;`

Comment: Okay I got it and I did the change but still there is an error in the malloc in the initialization funciton..

Comment: @Zok So I can see that you're still using your for loop: `for (i=0; i < num->nbrCell ;i++)`, in initialisation there is `num->nbrCell = 0`. This is why you never iterate.

Comment: Yeah now I believe the problems comes from this loop ! any suggestion?

Comment: @Zok Setting `num->nbrCell ` correctly or using my loop.

Comment: Using `while (newC != NULL)` is way more practical to me.

Comment: Okay now I used your procedure that you wrote above , I still get an error of memory , whether I used while(newC) or while(newC!=NULL) there is always 1 bloc that wasn't free'd

Comment: Updated as you wanted

Comment: You need to `free(num);` after freeing all of the nodes

Comment: @Zok " So in your supression() you need to add free(num); num = NULL; but otherwise your code should work" – jayant 1 hour ago I don't see it in your code...

Comment: Yes I just noticed that and now it works perfectly !!! Thank you so much guys ! I appreciate your help

Comment: @Zok You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer, I'm going to bed now.